# Javascript calendar displaying month and days

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a calendar where the month and year show at the top, with the days on single line (number line format) below. I want to get the next and previous months after clicking a button.

However, it only works after one click and I cant get the correct amount of days to display for the month.

```js
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var d = new Date();
var label = month[d.getMonth()];
var year = d.getFullYear();
var day = d.getDate();
document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = label + " " + year;
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = day;

//display days
var daysInMonths = [31, (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

document.getElementById("prevBtn").addEventListener("click", previousMonth);

function previousMonth() {
  label = month[d.getMonth() - 1];
  document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = label + " " + year;
}

document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", nextMonth);

function nextMonth() {
  label = month[d.getMonth() + 1];
  if (label > 11) {
    year = d.getFullYear() + 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = label + " " + year;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="left button" id="prevBtn">&lang;</span>
    <span><h1 id="mon"></h1></span>
    <span class="right button" id="nextBtn">&rang;</span>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="days"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to change `d` to be the new month. every time you are clicking the previous button, you are taking today's date (December) and subtracting 1 month (November). So it just keeps displaying November.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a pre-written datepicker widget? Is this a learning exercise?

Comment: I wasn’t sure how to modify the date picker the way I needed

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few modifications below as per my comment above.

```
var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
var today = new Date();
var label = month[today.getMonth()];
var mm = today.getMonth(); // keep track of the month
var year = today.getFullYear(); // keep track of the year
var day = today.getDate();
document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = label + " " + year;
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = day;

//display days
var daysInMonths = [31, (((year%4==0)&&(year%100!=0))||(year%400==0)) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

document.getElementById("prevBtn").addEventListener("click", previousMonth);

function previousMonth() {
    mm -= 1; // decrement the month
    if (mm < 0) { // if we go before January
        mm = 11; // go to December
        year -= 1; // of previous year
    }
    label = month[mm];
    document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = label + " " + year;
}

document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", nextMonth);
function nextMonth(){
    mm += 1; // increment month
    if (mm > 11) { // if we go after December
        mm = 0; // go to January
        year += 1; // of next year
    }
    document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = label + " " + year;
}
```